# using knockout extender to not allow an array of characters

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have been reading about the knockout extenders http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/extenders.html

I am trying to figure out given an input I would like an extender that has an array of special characters and does not allow the special character into the input.  but I'm afraid I can't figure out what I am doing.

```
this.firstName = ko.observable("").extend({doNotAllow: ['<','>','%','&']});


ko.extenders.doNotAllow = function(target, doNotAllow) {
     /*replace any occurrences specialchars with nothing */
    return target; 
};
```

Comment: Hmm? Currently your code doesn't do *anything* at all. Have you tried any kind of implementation yet? Let us know what specifically went wrong so we can help more easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would like to use `extend` to remove those characters you can simply use a `regularExpression` inside your extender function to validate your string and then `update` the original observable with new value.

Working Example:https://jsfiddle.net/kyr6w2x3/26/

**USING ko.extend**

```
function AppViewModel(first, last) {
    this.firstName = ko.observable(first).extend({ doNotAllow:['<','>','%','&'] });
}



 ko.extenders.doNotAllow = function(target, charachters) {
    target.validationMessage = ko.observable();

    //define a function to do validation for special characters 
    function validate(newValue) {
    // you can change regularExpression based on what you exactly want to be removed by using charachters parameter or just changing below expression 
      target(newValue.replace(/[&\/\\#,+()$~%.'":*?<>{}]/g, '') ); 
    }

    //initial validation
    validate(target());

    //validate whenever the value changes
    target.subscribe(validate);

    //return the original observable
    return target;
};

ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel("Type Special Characters"));
```

HTML :

```
<input data-bind='value: firstName, valueUpdate: "afterkeydown"' />
```

Here is a simple way of what you want to do

**USING NON-ko.extend**

```
 function AppViewModel(first) {
  var self = this;

  self.firstName = ko.observable(first);
  self.firstName.subscribe(function (newValue) {
    if (newValue) {
      self.firstName(newValue.replace(/[&\/\\#,+()$~%.'":*?<>{}]/g, '') ); 
    }
  });
}
ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel("Type Special Characters"));
```

HTML :

```
 <input data-bind='textInput: firstName' />
```