# Knockout JS Special characters validation

Tags: validation, knockout.js

I'm trying to disable my user input so they cannot use special characters, I've tried looking for solutions but was unable to find any.

e.g I don't want my Clint to be able to enter the following characters in the input box: {{!@#$%^&*()_+=}}

please help.

This is my current code

```
self.modelView = {
    Id: ko.observable(),
    Name: ko.observable().extend({
        required: true,
        minLength: 2,
        maxLength: 25

    }),
    Address: ko.observable().extend({
        required: true,
        minLength: 2,
        maxLength: 25
    })
};
```

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38665159/using-knockout-extender-to-not-allow-an-array-of-characters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the code, it looks as if you are using knockout-validation, and it supports html5 attribs:

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: myProp" pattern="^[a-z0-9].*" />
```

The pattern-attrib will take an regular expression, to fit your requirements

Answer (score 0):

Name: ko.observable().extend({
            required: true,
            pattern: ^[a-z0-9].*
        });